# Recover random deleted keyfile from ext4 disk

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, luks

Recently, I stored a random keyfile for a LUKS encrypted drive on an unencrypted ext4 USB stick, since I was between OSs and needed to be able to access it. Later, my new OS was installed and I moved the keyfile to the drive with the OS on it and deleted it from the USB drive.

Some time after I deleted the file, the OS failed and I decided to reinstall, forgetting to backup the keyfile first. Thus, I think my only hope is to try to find the deleted keyfile off of the USB drive.

The drive I am trying to unlock holds backups and other data, the most notable of which is the files for my password manager. I am not certain this is the only copy of these, but my next guess would be an SD card that is currently missing, and I would rather just be able to recover all my data.

So far, I have tried to recover the file by running `ext4magic -m` on an image of the USB drive. Once it finished I looked through the `application/octet-stream` directory of it's recovered files and narrowed it down to one file through running `file` on the files (most weren't actually `application/octet-stream`!) and `vim`ing the rest to see if they looked like random data. I tried unlocking the disk with this file, but it failed.

What else should I do to try to recover my keyfile?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you could try reading every block of the USB drive, selecting the appropriate length, and trying it as a key.

I wouldn't hold out much hope.  The deleted data could have been "trimmed" and thus gone back into the wear leveling pool.

---

A starting point for a command:

```
dd if=<device> skip=<block-number> bs=4096 count=1 \
    | dd bs=<key-length> count=1 \
    | cryptsetup open ... --keyfile - ...
```

This would then be in a loop of the possible block numbers, and I wouldn't exclude anything.